# How to insert Hint text into auth.login form

Tags: web2py

I would like to insert labels like "Email" and "password" as hint text inside the auth.login form.

Could anybody suggest how to do this?

Thanks in advance

A thinker!!

Answer (score 4):

If you want the hint to appear next to or below the form input field (depending on the form style you are using), you can use the `comment` attribute of the relevant `auth_user` table fields.

```
db.auth_user.email.comment = 'Enter your email address'
db.auth_user.password.comment = 'Enter your password'
```

If you want the hint to appear directly in the input field using the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, you can customize the `auth_user` table field widgets:

```
db.auth_user.email.widget = lambda f,v: SQLFORM.widgets.string.widget(f, v,
    _placeholder='Enter your email address')
```

See [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#Widgets) for more about widgets.

Note, older browsers don't support the `placeholder` attribute, so you may need some Javascript to make that work on older browsers.

If you just want the hints to appear on the login form (but not the registration or profile forms), you can put the above code in the `user()` function or the /default/user.html view:

```
def user():
    if request.args(0) == 'login':
        db.auth_user.email.comment = 'Enter your email address'
        etc.
    return dict(form=auth())
```

Otherwise, the code can go in a model file, any time after `auth` has been defined, in which case, it will affect all forms that include those fields.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I do want the hint fields for all auth forms. Let me try the ones you suggested first. Thanks again!!